# Put custom view inside a another

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I need to **extends** a ListView to create a custom component.
I would like to put search button at the bottom left floating.
When I run generate error in onMessure.

This code is a fragment, the original code has many other things.

I try to change ViewGroup parent to null, but I receive the same error.

```
mPainelView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.longlist_painel, null);
```

Custom View:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/longlist_painel_seek"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" /></FrameLayout>
```

Extended ListView:

```
public class List2 extends ListView {
    private View mPainelView;

    private int mPainelViewWidth;
    private int mPainelViewHeight;

    public List2(Context context) {
        super(context);
        createPainel();
    }

    public List2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        createPainel();
    }

    public List2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        createPainel();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mPainelView != null) {
            measureChild(mPainelView, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            mPainelViewWidth = mPainelView.getMeasuredWidth();
            mPainelViewHeight = mPainelView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        if (mPainelView != null) {
            mPainelView.layout(0, this.getBottom()-mPainelViewHeight,  mPainelViewWidth, mPainelViewHeight);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        drawChild(canvas, mPainelView, getDrawingTime());
    }


    private void createPainel(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mPainelView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.longlist_painel, this);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChild(ViewGroup.java:3098)
at com.rodrigo.comp.LongList2.onMeasure(List2.java:40)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8173)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to extend ListView, you can put views on top of each other with RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        />        
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Search"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This code is a example.
I have a extended ListView with many overrides for other things.

Answer (score 0):

first my english is not my mother language,i came into the same problem at the same time, so i googled this and find u, the nullpointer exception is throwed when it invoked the "measurChild" , i found that your mPainelView 's layoutParams is null , so the exception throwed.

if u change the inflate method to "inflater.inflate(R.layout.longlist_painel, yourlistview, false);"

u can solve this